# How to add new value for SKU price in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am new in **Magento** , I created my code to remove the special offer
and to add new price for SKU.

I could remove the special offer but I could not add the new price for SKUs. How can this be done?

My code is as follows:

```
$productIds[][] = array('DF-12''200','DF-98''300','DF-87''400');

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // <- careful with this
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'sku', array('in' => $productIds[0])
    )
    ->load();

foreach ($products as $_product){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    $product->setprice($productIds[1])
    $product->setOffertext('');
    $product->setSpecialFromDate('');
    $product->setSpecialToDate('');
    $product->setSpecialPrice('');
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Which error you are facing while used above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you're forming the array containing your products' SKU and prices, it seems off to me. But since I can only speculate on that part with the given information, an example of how I'd programmatically update smaller product collections might be of more help. This snippet works for me in a backend model:

```
// array('sku' => price )
$productPricesBySku = array('DF-1234' => 180.00, 'DF-1235' => 99.95);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')             // optional
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date') // optional
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date')   // optional
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in'=>array_keys($productPricesBySku)));

foreach($collection as $_product){

    if(!($price=$productPricesBySku[$_product->getSku()])) continue;    
    // no need to load the product again
    // just set the data directly on our collection-item and save it    
    $_product->setPrice((float)$price)
        ->setSpecialFromDate('')
        ->setSpecialToDate('')
        ->setSpecialPrice('')
        ->save();

}
```

(To prevent memory exhaustion on large collections you should use the **[Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Iterator](http://freegento.com/doc/dd/dcf/class_mage___core___model___resource___iterator.html)** rather than foreach-loops. You can read up on that [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/) for instance.)